# Capture a customer's bank card details without charging them in Stripe

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I want to use Stripe to capture a client's bank card number on registration on my website to validate and save it **in Stripe**. But not to charge. Instead I want to charge them in the future. Is it possible via Stripe API? How?

**update**:

Does this do what I want?

```
# Get the credit card details submitted by the form
token = request.POST['stripeToken']

# Create a Customer
customer = stripe.Customer.create(
  source=token,
  description="Example customer"
)
```

Comment: From the Stripe FAQ:  https://support.stripe.com/questions/can-i-save-a-card-and-charge-it-later

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher, in that it says "# charge the Customer instead of the card". it creates a customer and charges them. but how "not to charge them"?

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher, or when I capture the card details, how can I save them? that link doesn't describe that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As talked about here in the stripe documentation:

https://stripe.com/docs/charges

In short: You don't actually keep the credit card information yourself.  You *really* don't want to do this as it creates a security environment that you want to avoid.  Seriously.  PCI compliance is a [huge book](https://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/).

Instead, they remember the credit card information and give you a token you can use to refer to that data with later.

From their example, in Ruby:

```
# Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
# See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
stripe.api_key = "sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2"

# Get the credit card details submitted by the form
token = request.POST['stripeToken']

# Create a Customer
customer = stripe.Customer.create(
  source=token,
  description="Example customer"
)

# Charge the Customer instead of the card
stripe.Charge.create(
  amount=1000, # in cents
  currency="usd",
  customer=customer.id
)

# YOUR CODE: Save the customer ID and other info in a database for later!

# YOUR CODE: When it's time to charge the customer again, retrieve the customer ID!

stripe.Charge.create(
  amount=1500, # $15.00 this time
  currency="usd",
  customer=customer_id # Previously stored, then retrieved
)
```

*EDIT BASED ON COMMENT*

This does exactly what you asked for.  It captures the card details, keeps them on Strip and then you can access them when you need to.

In particular, note this lines:

```
# YOUR CODE: Save the customer ID and other info in a database for later!

# YOUR CODE: When it's time to charge the customer again, retrieve the customer ID!

stripe.Charge.create(
  amount=1500, # $15.00 this time
  currency="usd",
  customer=customer_id # Previously stored, then retrieved
)
```

WHEN IT IS TIME to charge, retrieve the token and do the charge.

Comment: that's doesn't answer my question. I don't want to keep the card information myself. re-read my question.

Comment: I don't understand, why "# YOUR CODE: When it's time to charge the customer again" -- why "again"?

Comment: The 'again' is there because the example code charged the customer.. and later, charged again. Obviously, you don't have to do the first charge.